# Kohana framework routing

Tags: php, framework, kohana, kohana-3

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с роутингом в фреймворке Kohana, у меня формируется url такого вида article/view/?id=4 нужно чтобы url был вида /article/name-of-article. В БД создана табличка 'url' с алиасами на транслите

Вот такой контроллер с помощью которого я забираю id

```
 $id = htmlspecialchars($this->request->query('id'));

    $sql = 'select * from articles where id='.$id;
    $articles = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)->execute()->as_array();

    if (count($articles) == 0) {
        HTTP::redirect('/articles');
    }
```

И вот так вывожу

```
<div class="card">
<a href="/article/view?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $intro_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></a>
<h3><a href="/article/view?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $h1; ?></a></h3>
<em><?php echo $changed; ?></em>
<div class="intro"><a href="/article/view?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $intro_text; ?></a></div>
<ul class="tags">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Kohana я бы подобное реализовал следующим образом:

**1:** Добавил в файл следующий роут-код `/application/bootstrap.php`:

```
Route::set('article', '/article/(<name>)')
    ->defaults (
        array (
            'controller' => 'article',
            'action' => 'index',
            'name' => ''
        )
    );
```

В массиве (параметрах) роута я указал имя файла контроллера `article`, имя метода `index` и параметр `name` по умолчанию.

**2:** Добавление контроллера `application/classes/Controller/Article.php`

```
<?php defined ('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Article extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        // Получаем параметр name из роута
        $name = Request::$initial->param('name');

        // Далее уже можешь делать все что угодно с ним
        // например выводить в шаблон
        $this->template->content = View::factory('article')
            ->set('name', $name);
    }
}
```